# JavaScript - Defer/Async with jQuery order issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I'm using the Semantic-UI framework, trying to build a website.

I have the following components into my  attributes.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"                      type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/visibility.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/dropdown.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/accordion.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/sidebar.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/rating.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/components/transition.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My issue: When I try to implement defer / async for the jquery, I think some js files load before it, and since they depend on the jQuery to function, I get console errors and the elements on my page won't function.

I want to know whether there is a method to make this work (functional at least in the latest Chrome / Firefox / Safari ) browsers.

---

Also, as a second question, is there any way to implement async for google fonts and other external resources ?

Comment: jQuery will be loaded first since that isn't async. Are you sure the problem is not that some of the deferred scripts require each other, and so will throw errors when not loaded in the right sequence? Personally, I'd either remove the `defer` or bundle/minify the script in to a single file which can easily be cached after the first request.

Comment: I cannot place them in a single file because i use CDN's for each. I could place the whole semantic-ui javascript file but it's huge. Since it makes multiple requests, I will try though, maybe the load time proves to be smaller.

The thing is that I also want jQuery to be async.

Comment: Right, then you can download them and manually place them in a single file. If you're using ASP.Net it has a bundling/minification library to do all this for you. You should also note that downloading one larger file will be much quicker than having to open/close multiple connections to different files.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. This is the error that i get when i use the tag on both scripts, so the jQuery needs to be loaded before everything else.

Comment: That is correct. There is no alternative for that; jQuery *has* to be loaded first. You cannot defer it

Comment: I found the actual issue.

I have a script after the body that initializes my elements.


This is causing the error because it tries to use the js files before they're loaded. How can I delay the execution of this ?